# How to debug Lazy, Suspense fallback in react 16.6.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading

I need to debug Lazy, Suspense fallback in react 16.6.3

Need to update Loading UI.

Looking for best solution.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#reactlazy-code-splitting-with-suspense

Comment: This was much more comfortable with react-loadable, where we could inspect with react devtools and simply set checkboxes for loading/pending and preview the result. I hope react team will provide better tooling around this in near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
const OtherComponent = lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Fallback />}>
      <OtherComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function Fallback() {
  // debug it here to your heart's content
  // same thing with "OtherComponent", debug it in component
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people stumbling upon this question now: in React Devtools (tried in FF), there's an option to tell the Suspense component to be suspended and display the fallback component:
[image]